# pass data from mySQL to an api in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask, data-conversion

I need to convert data from mySQL to JSON in Python using Flask.
I'm use the conversion directly in mySQL but it gives me error.
this is the code.

```
@app.route('/getdata')
def getdata():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**app.connDBConfig)

    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = "SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('nome', columnName, 'cognome', columnSur,)) from table;"

    cursor.execute(query)

    data = ""
    for elem in cursor:
        data = elem

    return jsonify(data)
```

This give me a stange JSON

[
"[{"nome": "enry", "cognome": "ford"}, {"nome": "michel", "cognome": "rodriguez"}, {"nome": "paul", "cognome": "roger"}, {"nome": "marcial", "cognome": "corz"}]"
]

why this and how I can fix it?

EDIT

if I use fethall it always give me all the JSON in an only object

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `cursor.fetchall()` or `cursor.fetchmany()` to get the data from the cursor. Documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)

The cursor object is NOT the data! , its just a handler that helps you get the data.

Comment: don't work, it always give me all the json in only one object