# Executing SQL Server Query in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have connected SQL Server with Python using pyodbc module. The script seems to have run correctly, however, I am getting errors when I try to execute my SQL statement.

This is what I have done:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import pyodbc


conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={SQL Server};'
    'Server=test\SQLEXPRESS;'
    'Database=test1;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )


 cursor = conn.cursor()


 def read(conn):
   print("Read")
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("select * from table")
   for row in cursor:
      print(f'row = {row}')
      print()



 read(conn) #to execute
```

I am wanting to execute a query that I would normally run within my SQL Server, but in Python:

```
  SELECT * FROM table
```

This is the error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL 
Server]Invalid object name 'Node'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I am actively researching this.

Comment: *"I am getting errors when I try to execute my SQL statement"* You forgot to include said errors.

Comment: I have just updated this

Comment: shouldn't you be using `cursor.fetchAll()`

Comment: like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942179/pass-data-from-mysql-to-an-api-in-flask/63942330#63942330

Comment: Let me try this now and see, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def read(conn):
   print("Read")
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("select * from table")
   allrows = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in allrows:
      print(f'row = {row}')
      print()
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't get that error that I had before, so I believe this works. The kernel is running now. By executing this code, it should give me the query output right? - Or must I 'call' the function? read()  ?

Comment: it should, you were just missing the fetchall() before you started looping thru the rows. You still need to call the read function

Comment: Oh wow it works, thank you so much for your knowledge